# Disabling the visual emphasis of the radio button label in Python wx?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Using the code posted below (generated with `wxglade`, tested on using wxPython 2.8.11.0, Python 2.7.1+, Ubuntu 11.04), I get this output:

[image: test.png]

Even if I removed the texts from the labels during instantiation, the label is *still* rendered when the buttons is pressed! How can I remove that effect; would it be possible to disable the label only, while keeping the radio buttons as a whole active? I simply don't want anything else rendered by the radiobuttons circle, regardless if it is selected or not.

EDIT: Just discovered that the little rectangle rendered by the radiobutton circle is apparently for focusing; so the question could be: is it possible to disable indication of focusing for radio buttons, while keeping all other functionality?

EDIT2: side question: how can I get the buttons' circles to be always centered in the middle of their spacer? Apparently, `wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL` doesn't work (try resizing the window, horizontally they still seem to be left aligned)

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# generated by wxGlade 0.6.3 on Tue Jan  6 03:40:06 2015

import wx

# begin wxGlade: extracode
# end wxGlade

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
    # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__init__
    kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
    self.radio_btn_1 = wx.RadioButton(self, -1, "")
    self.radio_btn_2 = wx.RadioButton(self, -1, "")
    self.radio_btn_3 = wx.RadioButton(self, -1, "")

    self.__set_properties()
    self.__do_layout()
    # end wxGlade

  def __set_properties(self):
    # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__set_properties
    self.SetTitle("Test Radiobuttons")
    self.SetSize((160, 100))
    # end wxGlade

  def __do_layout(self):
    # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__do_layout
    sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer_2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    sizer_2.Add(self.radio_btn_1, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 0)
    sizer_2.Add(self.radio_btn_2, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 0)
    sizer_2.Add(self.radio_btn_3, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 0)
    sizer_1.Add(sizer_2, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
    self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
    self.Layout()
    # end wxGlade

# end of class MyFrame


if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
  wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
  frame_1 = MyFrame(None, -1, "")
  app.SetTopWindow(frame_1)
  frame_1.Show()
  app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got this, both the focusing/visual emphasis, and the centering:

[image: test.png]

- For the focusing, I set up the radio buttons to bind on `EVT_SET_FOCUS`; then, I have instantiated - but not placed - an empty Panel; then as soon as the focus handler hits, I set the focus to the unplaced Panel; and this seems to remove the visual focus
- For the centering, it is actually important that there is a structure like this:

[image: wxglade.png]

... that is: you have first a 3-way horizontal sizer; but inside it, it's first level children must be (1-way) vertical sizer - and *none* of these may be set to wx.EXPAND! Then, the child vertical sizers are aligned wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL in respect to the horizontal sizer - and the radio buttons inside them, are aligned wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL.

Here is the now working code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# generated by wxGlade 0.6.3 on Tue Jan  6 03:40:06 2015

# [http://osdir.com/ml/wxpython-users/2010-03/msg00619.html wxpython-users - Re: [wxPython-users] Re: Possible to prevent focus on a wx.TextCtrl? - msg#00619 - Recent Discussion OSDir.com]

import wx

# begin wxGlade: extracode
# end wxGlade

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
    # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__init__
    kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
    self.focpanel = wx.Panel(self, -1) # just has to exist, doesn't need to be added anywhere in the frame - will still take away the focus
    self.radio_btn_1 = wx.RadioButton(self, -1, "")
    self.radio_btn_2 = wx.RadioButton(self, -1, "")
    self.radio_btn_3 = wx.RadioButton(self, -1, "")

    self.radio_btn_1.Bind(wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS, self.killFocus) #not EVT_ACTIVATE
    self.radio_btn_2.Bind(wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS, self.killFocus)
    self.radio_btn_3.Bind(wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS, self.killFocus)

    self.__set_properties()
    self.__do_layout()
    # end wxGlade

  def killFocus(self, event):
    #print("AAA" + str(event))
    self.focpanel.SetFocus()

  def __set_properties(self):
    # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__set_properties
    self.SetTitle("Test Radiobuttons")
    self.SetSize((160, 100))
    # end wxGlade

  def __do_layout(self):
    # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__do_layout
    sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer_2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    sizer_8 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer_7 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer_6 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer_6.Add(self.radio_btn_1, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0)
    sizer_2.Add(sizer_6, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 0)
    sizer_7.Add(self.radio_btn_2, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0)
    sizer_2.Add(sizer_7, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 0)
    sizer_8.Add(self.radio_btn_3, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0)
    sizer_2.Add(sizer_8, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 0)
    sizer_1.Add(sizer_2, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
    self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
    self.Layout()
    # end wxGlade

# end of class MyFrame


if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
  wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
  frame_1 = MyFrame(None, -1, "")
  app.SetTopWindow(frame_1)
  frame_1.Show()
  app.MainLoop()
```